# Is there  a workaround to get Lips (XBox360) to import songs from an iPod Touch or iPhone?

Tags: xbox-360, ios, lips

After futzing around with this for a while I finally checked the supports site and saw that the iPhone/iPod-touch OS does not support the protocol necessary to upload songs into Lips, although the lower end iPod players are supported.

Does anyone know a workaround, or perhaps an iPhone app that emulates the old interface such that this can be made to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now there isn't any way to import songs to Lips from an iPod Touch or iPhone, you can't even stream music for any other game.